# I want to install WSL without Microsoft store, is that possible?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 10 home.
I don't want to install WSL via Microsoft store because I don't want to open a Microsoft account.

In the past it was possible to install WSL via Powershell but now the standard is to use the store; although that standard, is there still any way to install it via Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question ; Yes, it is possible.
Here is how I have done this:

I have opened the Command Prompt (CMD) by clicking the "Start" button and typing CMD in my keyboard and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I ran:

```
wsl --install
```

I got the error:

> The requested operation requires elevation

So I just closed CMD, re-opened it as administrator and then re-ran the above command (`wsl --install`) and the installation started.

After the installation I understood that I should reboot the system (mere CMD rebooting didn't help) but after rebooting Windows I could start WSL and I can now work with it, with a `root` user though:
Strangely, after the install, I wasn't asked to create a new username and password; this might be a legacy from older WSL versions I had installed a few years back.

Comment: Or you could simply install it using windows features.