# running as administrator, but still needing elevation?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Ubuntu via WSL on Windows 10. I spin up a command prompt as administrator (i.e. I right click on the command prompt icon, and select `Run as Administrator`), and run `wsl --update` however, I get an error message:

`The requested operation requires elevation.`

I'm running the prompt as administrator, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You’re not running the PowerShell or Command prompt as an Administrator elevating the permissions of the process. You should do that, right click, and select the option in the right click menu[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1687551/i-want-to-install-wsl-without-microsoft-store-is-that-possible/1687753#1687753)

Comment: I should clarify this, I'm right-clicking and saying "Run as Administrator", I'll edit the post as well.

Comment: The only reason you would get that message is if the command prompt wasn’t actually elevated.

Comment: The "elevation" of a process involves re-starting the process with a special "owner" that isn't technically the 'administrator'.  Some (documented) operations mess up the elevation and the privileges. Which is just one reason why you do get that message from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Are you supposed to shutdown WSL?  Is this the documented update process now?

Comment: The correct way to install Ubuntu is from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue here, but harrymc is correct that installing a Linux image into WSL is done via the Store. If you're trying to install Ubuntu, use the correct method and let us know whether that works. If you're trying to follow a particular guide, let us know the steps you HAVE done and the steps you've expected to follow.

Comment: @user165568 what operations? Can you elaborate?